# Execute the script with special command iceweasel ( which is a firefox webbrowser for debian )

Tags: python

I have a problem, I would like to execute my python script but with special command like this:

```
iceweasel 'info.py server.py path_install.py'
```

this command must be typed on the client and we open the page with informations :

```
info.py (= os and ip of client)
server.py
path_install.py
```

But I really don't understand where to start this ...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but I think you should start with [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for command line arguments to Python programs.

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: @user3752820 Do you want to execute your python script with an other script called iceweasel which would then display info on the arguments?

Comment: @AshokaLella : So, Yes it must be used in command line ( with debian ). Actually, I must to create a script. I need to use this script like this : iceweasel 'info.py adress_server path_install' This command must open a new page in iceweasel with some informations : path_install IP of client OS of client My main problem, is to obtain execution of this command: iceweasel info.py adress_server path_install –

Comment: @user3752820 is iceweasel a browser(firefox fork)? if so, it takes only urls as input arguments.

Comment: @user3752820 Please, correct your original question, add a note, that `iceweasel` is web browser (Firefox based) and correct the `.py`, which you show in two different manners.

Comment: @AshokaLella : Iceweasel is a firefox browser for debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Requirements Review

It seems, you want to:

- call the program from command line
- pass in arbitrary number of python file names
- for each python file, print some details about that file

## Concept

- use `docopt` for command line argument parsing (`argparse`, `plac` and others are also alternatives)
- print some information about the file (as it is not very clear, what details about Python files you want to report - modify it as you like)

## `iceweasel.py`

```
"""
Usage:
    iceweasel.py <pythonfile>...
    iceweasel.py -h

Prints internal details for arbirtary set of <pythonfile> files.
"""
import os

def srcdetails(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        content = f.read()
    shortname = os.path.split(fname)[-1]
    size = len(content)
    words = len(content.split())
    templ = """
    ---- {fname} -----
    short name: {shortname}
    size: {size}
    words: {words}
    """
    print templ.format(**locals())

def main(pythonfiles):
    for fname in pythonfiles:
        srcdetails(fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    pythonfiles = args["<pythonfile>"]
    main(pythonfiles)
```

## Use it

Install `docopt` first

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Call the command without arguments:

```
$ python iceweasel.py
Usage:
    iceweasel.py <pythonfile>...
    iceweasel.py -h
```

Try help

```
$ python iceweasel.py -h
Usage:
    iceweasel.py <pythonfile>...
    iceweasel.py -h

Prints internal details for arbirtary set of <pythonfile> files.
```

Use it for one file:

```
$ python iceweasel.py iceweasel.py 

    ---- iceweasel.py -----
    short name: iceweasel.py
    size: 692
    words: 74
```

Use it for multiple files, using wildcards:

```
$ python iceweasel.py ../*.py

    ---- ../camera2xml.py -----
    short name: camera2xml.py
    size: 567
    words: 47


    ---- ../cgi.py -----
    short name: cgi.py
    size: 612
    words: 63


    ---- ../classs.py -----
    short name: classs.py
    size: 485
    words: 44
```

## Conclusions

- command line parsing can be easy in Python

  - `argparse` seems is standard part of Python since version 2.7
  - `argparse` can do a lot, but requires rather complex calls on many lines
  - `plac` is nice alternative, can server quickly in most cases
  - `docopt` seems to me to be the most flexible and at the same time shortest in required lines of code
- If you do not want to call `python` at each invocation of your script, there are alternatives

  - use shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` as first line of your script, set it executable, and then you can even remove the `.py` extension. Works only on *nix, not for Windows
  - write your own `setup.py` and task it to install the script. Works everywhere, but requires a bit more coding. On the other hand it can be very effective solution if you expect more users using the script as it can significantly simplify the installation procedure.

Comment: So,

Yes it must be used in command line ( with debian ).

Actually, I must to create a script.

I need to use this script like this :

    iceweasel  `info.py adress_server path_install`

This command must open a new page in iceweasel with some informations :


    path_install
    IP of client
    OS of client

My main problem, is to obtain execution of this command 

    iceweasel  `info.py adress_server path_install`